# How to specify PHP static function argument from terminal

Tags: php, terminal, arguments, static-methods

I have a script, which executes by `Example::main("file.csv");`.
I want to run the script from the terminal, but how can I achieve, so I don't define the argument in the script, but in the terminal, like `php Example.php file.csv`?
Thanks!

Comment: Command line arguments are in `$argv` array

Comment: Can you please give me an example for this case?

Comment: Start with `print_r($argv)`

Comment: Resolved with Example::main($argv[1]).

Comment: Answer your question then.

Answer (score -1):

`Example::main($argv[1]);` is the solution.